# Publish Wordpress posts in Google plus?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, google-plus

I need a WP plugin that updates my google+ when I write a new blog post. I want something automatic that doesn#t require to +1 the  blog post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look here: http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/sharing-posts-to-google-1

> Google+ has specifically disallowed robo-posting. They want to keep
>   the  quality of interaction high and so if you can't be bothered to
>   manually  paste the link, they don't want you posting on Google+.

But it seems that there is a script: http://www.nextscripts.com/google-plus-automated-posting

Comment: I purchased the full version of this and it's working flawlessly...exactly what I needed for Twitter and Google +.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone's still looking for options on this...

Hootsuite can post directly to Google+ pages, either directly or from a blog rss feed. Their free account lets you add two rss feeds and report the content to up to five social accounts, including google+ pages.

Another option I've seen but haven't tried is Jetpack... I believe that now has options to repost your blog to Google+.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it!!!!!!!
I tried Gpressor & WPGPlus plugins but they are unreliable (I think Google blocks them?).
So here is how I do it:
1) Create WP post. Syndicate to Blogger. (I use Links Alpha for this).
2) Go to blogger account. Select “posts”. Click share.
Voila Blogger posts to the Google+page!
Note: I have a personal gmail account and g+ profile under which I have my g+ page for my business.
I had to transfer my blogger blog from my personal gmail account to my business gmail account (we use Google Apps).
Then when I click Share in blogger it shares from my business domain to my business page….
It seems you cannot share from a personal gmail account to a business page.

Answer (score 0):

I think this plugin http://www.nextscripts.com/google-plus-automated-posting works much better. I tried this for my website http://gesertelunjuk.com and it was very useful.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a completely free solution to post to Google+ from any RSS feed: http://bamajr.com/2013/02/16/posting-to-google-plus-via-email/

Be sure to read the comment to complete the full process: http://bamajr.com/2013/02/16/posting-to-google-plus-via-email/#comment-658

I know Full Answers are preferred, but it is a LONG and detailed process with lots of images and I don't want to copy/paste, upload images, then reformat the process for Stack Overflow.